# Good resources for Star Wars Saga Edition

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition

I was wondering if anyone knew where some good resources for SWSE (Star Wars: Saga Edition) would be. They closed down their official site besides the Dawn of Defiance campaign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not specific for Saga edition, the following are of general SW Gaming use:

Wookiepedia
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page your best source for setting information.

http://www.starwarsmap.com/ Rest of the site is pretty lame, but it's a good map.

http://starwarsatlas.uw.hu/thelist.htm more useful, but less canonical, maps

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend www.d20radio.com and the forums in particular; the members there are very helpful and pitch in on all sorts of questions.  In addition, the associated podcasts (Order 66) are an excellent resource.

If you are a paying member of DDI, the WOTC Star Wars forums remain up and definitely active.

Answer (score 0):

I actually look to Star Wars Expanded Universe as well as non-Star Wars sources for ideas for campaigns, villains, etc.

For example, the novels Death Troopers and Red Harvest provide the idea of a zombie story. Not done often in Star Wars, but can make for a creepy adventure.

TV shows like Dollhouse or other RPG systems like ShadowRun make for some interesting "cross over" ideas. You could have adventures doing different "runs" that go bad. Or where your characters get memory wiped after each adventure, etc.

Whatever you use, make sure you make it feel like Star Wars though.

That's what I've done for GM'ing and it makes for some interesting and fun adventures.

Another example of what I've done....I took inspiration from Batman and created a "Sith Jester", ie a Sith who is off his rocker a tad like the Joker. The story still feels Star Wars, but with a unique twist of a villain not traditionally seen. And so far he is a character the players love to hate. :)